# Load Cell Decreasing Output

Tags: load-cell, arduino-uno

I built the following weight system using a  [Load Cell](https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/datasheet-3133.pdf) and [Hx711.](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf)
[image: structureHoldingLoadCell][image]

I am using an Arduino UNO and running the calibration sketch in [HX711 library.](https://github.com/bogde/HX711)

However, I noted one interesting behavior that you guys might have come across. My serial output from the Arduino IDE console is accurate in the beginning. Then, as time progresses it slowly starts to decrease. This is even further evidenced when I remove the object, and instead of converging to zero it goes to negative.[image: erroneous output]

Would this indicate faulty load cell behavior, problem with the structure that holds it, the wiring, or just the nature of the sketch which is to simply calibrate? The reason for this question is that before I begin to write the code for this load cell application, I want to make sure it is accurate. Also, I attach a picture of my connection so we can discard this source of error and brainstorm.Thanks. [image]

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the supply voltage from the load cell for a while and let it cool off, then reapply the supply voltage and make a measurement?

Comment: It is due to amplifier drift and load cell hysteresis

Comment: Marko, I was reading a little bit more about these topics, but from my quick search there is no absolute way to completely get rid of them right? Have you had any experience trying to address this phenomena?

Comment: Not familiar with HX711, AD7190 and similar ADC from Analog Devices do have a chopper to eliminate the drift. High quality load cells have low temp. coefficient and minimal hysteresis. Further ADC from AD has an auto tare function, if you previously set the tare and when it detects that load cell is unloaded it auto zeroes.